# Tcl Tk select rows in two different tablelists

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I created two different tablelists by Nehmeti in different frames and some bindings.

```
set pfd(panWin) [panedwindow $pfd(bottomFr).pw -showhandle 1 -orient vertical -sashpad 0 -sashrelief raised -sashwidth 2]
set pfd(frMesswerte)   [frame $pfd(panWin).frMesswerte]
set pfd(frKlaffNeupkt) [frame $pfd(panWin).frKlaffNeupkt]
set pfd(noteb) [iwidgets::notebook $pfd(frKlaffNeupkt).noteb]
pack $pfd(noteb) -anchor nw -expand 1 -fill both
set pfd(frKlaffungen) [$pfd(noteb) add -label Klaffungen]

set pfd(tali_mw) [tablelist::tablelist $pfd(frMesswerte).li.tali_mw \
                                                   -columns {0 "oid" l \
                                                             0 "status" l \
                                                             0 "art" l \
                                                             0 "sollTyp" l \
                                                             0 "Nr" l \
                                                             0 "Typ" l \
                                                             0 "Gst" l \
                                                             0 "Hz" r \
                                                             0 "V" r \
                                                             0 "S" r \
                                                             0 "Q" r \
                                                             0 "L" r \
                                                             0 "AK" l\
                                                             0 "LSEX" l \
                                                             0 "lfdNrGes" l}\
                                                   -exportselection 1 \
                                                   -labelbackground #EEEEEE \
                                                   -background white \
                                                   -labelfont $tableheadfont\
                                                   -font $tableinhfont\
                                                   -stretch 12\
                                                   -selectbackground $vmVConfig::setVar(activeBG) \
                                                   -selectforeground $vmVConfig::setVar(activeFG) \
                                                   -selectmode single\
                                                   -borderwidth 1 \
                                                   -labelborderwidth 1 \
                                                   -selectborderwidth 0 \
                                                   -tooltipaddcommand [::itcl::code $this tooltipAddCmd] \
                                                   -tooltipdelcommand [::itcl::code $this tooltipDelCmd] \
                                                   -xscrollcommand [list vmTkTools::configSB "h" $pfd(mw_scrx)]\
                                                   -yscrollcommand [list vmTkTools::configSB "v" $pfd(mw_scry)]]

set body [$pfd(tali_mw) bodypath]                                             
bind $body <Double-1> +[::itcl::code $this doubleKlickMesswerte %x %y %W]
bind $body <Button-1> +[::itcl::code $this loeschePfeil]
bind $body <Button-3> +[bind TablelistBody <Button-1>]
bind $body <Button-3> +[::itcl::code $this popUp $pfd(popUpMenu) %X %Y]

set pfd(tali_klaff) [tablelist::tablelist $pfd(frKlaffungen).li.tali_klaff \
                                                -columns {0 "oid" l 0 "Nr" l 0 "dX" r 0 "dY" r 0 "GwX" r 0 "GwY" r 0 "Rdz" r}\
                                                -labelbackground #EEEEEE \
                                                -background white \
                                                -labelfont $tableheadfont\
                                                -font $tableinhfont\
                                                -stretch 7\
                                                -selectbackground $vmVConfig::setVar(activeBG) \
                                                -selectforeground $vmVConfig::setVar(activeFG) \
                                                -selectmode single\
                                                -labelrelief groove \
                                                -borderwidth 1 \
                                                -labelborderwidth 1 \
                                                -selectborderwidth 0 \
                                                -xscrollcommand [list vmTkTools::configSB "h" $pfd(klaff_scrx)]\
                                                -yscrollcommand [list vmTkTools::configSB "v" $pfd(klaff_scry)]]

set body [$pfd(tali_klaff) bodypath]                                             
bind $body <Double-1> +[::itcl::code $this anzeigePpMp4Klaff]
bind $body <Button-3> +[bind TablelistBody <Button-1>]
bind $body <Button-3> +[::itcl::code $this popUp $pfd(popUpKlaffungen) %X %Y]
```

These two tablelists are filled with content later. The number in column "oid" in pfd(tali_mw) corresponds to the number in column "oid" in pfd(tali_klaff).

Now I want to select a row  in pfd(tali_mw) and the corresponding row being selected in pfd(tali_klaff)

I wrote the following method.

```
itcl::body vmMaskHelmert::selPPorMPinTableMWKLAFF {oidbez id} {
   foreach tag [$data(canRef) gettags $id] {
      if {[string range $tag 0 7] == "PASSPKT_"} {
         set art "pass"
      } elseif {[string range $tag 0 7] == "MASSPKT_"} {
         set art "masse"
      }
   }

   set inhaltMW [$pfd(tali_mw) get 0 end]
   set idx 0
   $pfd(tali_mw) selection clear 0 end
   foreach zeile $inhaltMW {
      set ken [lindex $zeile 0]
      if { [string compare $ken $oidbez] == 0 } {
         set rowMW $idx
         break
      }
      incr idx
   }

   set inhaltKLAFF [$pfd(tali_klaff) get 0 end]
   set idx 0 ; # Zaehler welche Zeile
   $pfd(tali_klaff) selection clear 0 end
   foreach zeile $inhaltKLAFF {
      set ken [lindex $zeile 0]
      if { [string compare $ken $oidbez] == 0 } {
         set rowKLAFF $idx
         break
      }
      incr idx
   }
   .
   .
   .
```

The argument "oidbez" is the oid in column 0 in both tablelists.

First I tried to go on like the following:

```
   $pfd(tali_mw) selection set $rowMW $rowMW
   $pfd(tali_klaff) selection set $rowKLAFF $rowKLAFF

   return
}
```

But the selection in pfd(tali_mw) was taken away.

So I tried the following:

```
   $pfd(tali_mw) selection set $rowMW $rowMW
   $pfd(tali_klaff) activate $rowKLAFF
   focus $pfd(tali_klaff)
   return
}
```

Now I see the selected row in pfd(tali_mw) and the corresponding row activated in pfd(tali_klaff). Unfortunately the focus command blocks the binded commands for the tablelist, for example I can't do any double click in pfd(tali_klaff).

Next I would try to select the row in pfd(tali_mw) and just change the background for the corresponding row in pfd(tali_klaff). But I want to avoid this way. Is there any possibility to select the two rows in the two tablelists? I have to sustain both tablelists, because they still have other functions. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should turn off exporting of the selection in *both* tablelists (`-exportselection 0`) otherwise selecting a thing in one list will stop you selecting a thing in the other. The selection referred to by that option is the `PRIMARY` selection, and can only be held by a single widget at a time (unless you do clever stuff with the `selection` command to present a more sophisticated model).

You might also need to add your own bindings for the `<<Cut>>`, `<<Copy>>` and possibly the `<<Paste>>` (virtual) events, depending on exactly what you are doing. Or you might reasonably not care very much about them in your application. That's finessing it…